# How to parse sql statement insert into to get values with pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a sql dump with several `insert into` like the following one

```
query ="INSERT INTO `temptable` VALUES (1773,0,'morne',0),(6004,0,'ATT',0)"
```

I'm trying to get only the values in a dataframe

```
(1773,0,'morne',0)
(6004,0,'ATT',0)
```

I tried

```
spark._jsparkSession.sessionState().sqlParser().parsePlan(query)
```

and get

```
'InsertIntoTable 'UnresolvedRelation `temptable`, false, false
+- 'UnresolvedInlineTable [col1, col2, col3, col4], [List(1773, 0, 
morne, 0), List(6004,0, 0, ATT, 0)]
```

But I don't know how to retrieve those lists of value

is there a way to get without hive?

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to get only list of values from multiple insert statements then you may try below

```
listOfInserts = [('''INSERT INTO temptable VALUES (1773,0,'morne',0),(6004,0,'ATT',0)''',),('''INSERT INTO temptable VALUES (1673,0,'morne',0),(5004,0,'ATT',0)''',)]

df = spark.createDataFrame(listOfInserts, ['VALUES'])

from pyspark.sql.functions import substring_index

df.select(substring_index(df.VALUES, 'VALUES', -1).alias('right')).show(truncate = False)
```

Comment: yes I'm trying to get only values in a df in rows for each list like <br/>
<br/>
+----+----+----+----+<br/>
|col1|col2|col3|col4|<br/>
+----+----+----+----+ <br/>
|1773|   0|morn|   0|<br/>
|6004|   0| ATT|   0|<br/>
|1773|   0|morn|   0|<br/>
|6004|   0| ATT|   0| <br/>
+----+----+----+----+<br/>